# How to use the vagrant vagrant-share 1.1.9

Tags: vagrant-plugin

I've already installed ngrok to  "/usr/bin" , but  still suggested that "The executable 'vagrant is trying to run was not found.
The 'executable is required to.
Run Vagrant share. If 'ngrok' is currently installed in a
Non-standard location, append that location to the PATH
Variable and run this command again. If 'ngrok' is not
Currently installed, it can be downloaded from the ngrok
Website:

https://ngrok.com/download
"

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a new terminal (in order to create a new session) and run the command again.